# Cómo puedo poner el resultado de php foreach en 3 columnas y no en 1

Tags: php, bootstrap, lista, foreach

Tengo este fichero pedido.php que lista todos los platos que tengo en mi BD. Tal como lo tengo me funciona bien y me lista los productos, pero en una sola columna, uno debajo de otro.
Ejemplo:

```
plato 1
plato 2
plato 3
plato 4
plato 5
plato 6
```

Lo que quiero es que se listen los productos en 3 columnas por orden de izquierda a derecha, tal que así:

Ejemplo:

```
Plato 1          Plato 2        Plato 3
Plato 4          Plato 5        Plato 6
...
```

Tengo un modelo vista controlador y una función listar en el controlador a la que llamo en el fichero pedido.php para que liste los platos.
Si me pudierais echar una mano para ponerlo en tres columnas por favor.

Este es mi fichero pedido.php

```php
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/../lib/controller/UsuarioController.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../lib/controller/PlatoController.php');

session_start();

$id = $_GET["p"];
$cnt = new PlatoController();
$list = $cnt->listarP();
?><html>
<body>
  <?php foreach ($list as $pl){ ?>
    <div class="container my-5 py-5">
      <!--Section: Content-->
      <section class="text-center">
        <!--Grid row-->
        <div class="row">
          <!--Grid column-->
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
            <img src="<?=$pl->getImagen()?>" height="200px">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="mb-1"><a
                  href="" class="font-weight-bold black-text"
                ><?=$pl->getNombre()?></a></p>
                <p class="mb-1"><strong><?=$pl->getPrecio()?> €</strong></p>
                <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-blue btn-rounded btn-sm px-3">Añadir</button>
                <a 
                  href="/WebBurger/public/detallesPlato.php?pl=<?=$pl->getId_plato()?>&pu=<?=$id?>"
                ><button type="button"
                class="btn btn-outline-blue btn-rounded btn-sm px-3 waves-effect"
                >Detalles</button></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Grid row-->
      </section>
      <!--Section: Content-->
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar una tabla.

Comment: Por que modificas de esa forma tu pregunta @JuanGomez ?

Comment: Por favor no generes más trabajo a los otros usuarios vandalizando tu publicación. Publicando en la red [SE] otorgaste derechos no revocables, bajo la [licencia CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) para que SE pueda distribuir su contenido. Por política de SE, cualquier clase de vandalismo será revertido. Si queres saber más sobre cómo eliminar una publicación, considera mirar: [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/22845).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este **foreach** no creo que tenga sentido ponerlo ahi, ya que tu objetivo es repetir la columna.

```
<?php foreach ($list as $pl){ ?>
    <div class="container my-5 py-5">
```

El **foreach** lo deberias poner en este punto

```
<!--Grid column-->

<?php foreach ($list as $pl){ ?>
<div class="col-sm-4">
//contenido php
</div>
```

Comment: perfecto, era eso, cambié el foreach y me salió bien. Muy amable!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que por cada plato estás generando un `.row` y esto ocasiona que cada uno de ellos ocupe una linea ya que un `.row` ocupa de manera natural todo el ancho del elemento padre.

Lo que podrías es crear un `.row` que englobe a todos tus platos y luego cada plato dentro de un `col-4` de esta manera consigues hacer que al ocupar cada plato 4 de las 12 celdas del **grid** al ir a meter el 4 ocurre un "salto de linea" por no tener espacio para mostrarse en la misma línea.

Te dejo un ejemplo del **HTML** de la estructura:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>Plato 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>Plato 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>Plato 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>Plato 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>Plato 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>Plato 6</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

Entonces, como bien te ha dicho el compañero **@Clinton Tapia Lagar**, la estructura que debes crear dinamicamente dentro de `foreach` debe de ser tus columnas, quedándote algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
<div class="row">

<?php foreach ($list as $pl) { ?>
    
    <!--Grid column-->
    <div class="col-4">
        <img src="<?=$pl->getImagen()?>" height="200px">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="mb-1"><a href="" class="font-weight-bold black-text"><?=$pl->getNombre()?></a></p>
                <p class="mb-1"><strong><?=$pl->getPrecio()?> €</strong></p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue btn-rounded btn-sm px-3">Añadir</button>
                <a href="/WebBurger/public/detallesPlato.php?pl=<?=$pl->getId_plato()?>&pu=<?=$id?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-blue btn-rounded btn-sm px-3 waves-effect">Detalles</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
    
</div>
```